# How to determine if file completed downloading in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I am doing the following very basic task in SSH.NET/C# to download a file from a remote server to a local path:

```
ConnectionInfo c = new PasswordConnectionInfo(remoteIP, port, username, password);
var sftp = new SftpClient(c);
sftp.Connect();
using (var stream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create))
{

//download the file to our local path
sftp.DownloadFile(fileName, stream);
stream.Close();

}

sftp.Disconnect();
```

Now to determine if the file completely downloaded successfully, would that just be if the code block reached stream.Close()? Or is there a more concrete way to determine if everything was written okay?

EDIT: [This post](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/349449) could be helpful to some if you want to see how many bytes have been downloaded. It also makes a primitive progress bar, which is convenient. I tested the code in the post and it does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs) for SSH.NET, `DownloadFile()` is a blocking operation and will not return until the file is written fully.

Additionally, calling `stream.Close()` inside of the using block is not needed, as the object will be Disposed when exiting the block.

Answer (score 0):

When I was working with SSH.NET a while back, for some reason I didn't know about or didn't like the fact that .DownloadFile had no return value.  Either way, this was the route I took at the time.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ConnectionInfo c = new PasswordConnectionInfo(remoteIP, port, username, password);
        var sftp = new SftpClient(c);

        try
        {

            using (StreamReader reader = sftp.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(line);
                }

            }

            File.WriteAllText(destinationFile, sb.ToString());

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // procress exception
        }
```